# Dropdown using CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am making a dropdown menu on one of my menu item.

ie: `| Home | About | Store | Contact |`

I want to create a dropdown menu for say About page...but Whenever I try to add

```
 <div id="snaznav"> <a href="#" id="home">Home</a>      
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="about">About</a>
<ul>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu1</li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu2</li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu3</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

Every next menu item gets disturbed as:

Home | About
                   Store |
                                Contact  |

I dont know..where the problem is?

My CSS code is:

```
#snaznav {

float:left;
height:42px;
top:151px;
width:670px;
}

#snaznav a {
float:left;
height:41px;
display:block;
}

#home {
background:url(http://www.abc.com/home.gif) no-repeat transparent;
background-position:0 -2px!important;
width:77px;
}

#about {
background:url(http://www.abc.com/about.gif) no-repeat transparent;
background-position:-78px -2px!important;
width:104px;
}

#store {
background:url(http://www.abc.com/storegif) no-repeat transparent;
background-position:-307px -2px!important;
width:82px;
}

#contactus {
background:url(http://www.abc.com/contact.gif) no-repeat transparent;
background-position:-388px -2px!important;
width:131px;
}
```

If you need anything to know, just say me !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you rewrite your HTML Code this way:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="snaznav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

So that the CSS you can apply this way:

#### CSS:

```
#snaznav ul {border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
#snaznav ul li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;}
#snaznav ul > li:hover {border: 1px solid #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
#snaznav ul li a:hover {background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #999;}
#snaznav ul > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid #fff;}
#snaznav ul > li ul {display: none; position: absolute; left: -1px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #666; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: 1px;}
#snaznav ul > li:hover ul {display: block;}
#snaznav ul > li ul li {display: block;} /* Vertical Menu */
#snaznav ul > li ul li {display: inline-block;} /* Horizontal Menu */​
```

#### Fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/VmHXb/1/ (Vertical)
 http://jsfiddle.net/VmHXb/3/ (Horizontal)

Comment: can you expand the dropdown menu items horizontally, in http://jsfiddle.net/VmHXb/2/ (Horizontal)